# CEPH, running a Cluster over the Internet

Tags: ceph

Are there any concerns in regards to security when running a CEPH Cluster on the Internet?

I could not find directly something which makes it no usuable for this use case. I dont need low I/O response times, I am fine with it.

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 2):

While auth to the cluster daemons is handled by cephx, the traffic is **NOT** encrypted.

So yes, there is a security concern.

Answer (score 1):

CEPH recommends that your cluster does not face the Internet.

> We recommend running a Ceph Storage Cluster with two networks: a public (front-side) network and a cluster (back-side) network.

They recommend having your cluster on the backend because of improved performance (which doesn't matter for your use case), but also **security**: having it on the backend helps combat DoS attacks.

> While most people are generally civil, a very tiny segment of the population likes to engage in what’s known as a Denial of Service (DoS) attack. When traffic between Ceph OSD Daemons gets disrupted, placement groups may no longer reflect an active + clean state, which may prevent users from reading and writing data. A great way to defeat this type of attack is to maintain a completely separate cluster network that doesn’t connect directly to the internet.

([Source](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/jewel/rados/configuration/network-config-ref/))

Answer (score 1):

I did end up with TincVPN, which is easy to setup and uses Public/Private keys, that connects all my Nodes.

But as I got told, thats not a good use case but it works, so meh.